# The right position of "although" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, writing

> ... .Obviously, this overhead is function of the amount of resources, M, and increasing M, although it provides better knowledge, it  results in a larger overhead.
>
> ... .Obviously, this overhead is function of the amount of resources, M, and although increasing M provides better efficency, it  results in a larger overhead.

Which one between these two sentences sounds better ? Do you have a better formulation ? should I say "a function" or just "function" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously, this overhead is **a** function of the amount of resources, M, and increasing M, although it provides better knowledge, **it** results in a larger overhead.
>
> Obviously, this overhead is **a** function of the amount of resources, M, and although increasing M provides better efficency, it results in a larger overhead.

I'd say the second sentence flows better. It's easier to mentally parse when there's one less comma-separated phrase interrupting you. If you were going to use the first, you should remove the highlighted *it*. This should not be included since, if you consider the sentence without the parenthetical *although it provides better knowledge*, it is this:

> increasing M it results in a larger overhead.

Which is obviously incorrect, and should be:

> increasing M results in a larger overhead.

In the second sentence, this doesn't apply, because the *it* is part of a separate phrase, and is a placeholder for *increasing M*. As a side note, *efficiency* was spelled wrong.

> ...although increasing M provides better efficiency, [increasing M] results in a larger overhead.

Finally, it should be *a function*, not *function*.